# Why is a button within <ItemTemplate> field appearing outside the column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, gridview

I am trying to create an editable gridview in Visual Studio. For one column, I am trying to add two buttons ("Edit" and "Delete"). However, the button is displayed outside the gridview, not in that column. How can I fix this? My code is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Options">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"/>
<ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks!

More code below, including the code for the gridview where I add the columns and their names. It reads in information from a sql server database

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>
<head><title>
Project
</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style8 {
        z-index: 1;
        left: 110px;
        top: 433px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .auto-style10 {
        z-index: 1;
        left: 267px;
        top: 440px;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>

    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style5 {
            width: 1651px;
            height: 379px;
            position: relative;
            top: 4px;
            left: 4px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .auto-style6 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            left: 1085px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .auto-style7 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 1300px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>
<style type="text/css">
/* <![CDATA[ */
#menuNav img.icon { border-style:none;vertical-align:middle; }
#menuNav img.separator { border-style:none;display:block; }
#menuNav img.horizontal-separator { border-style:none;vertical-align:middle; }
#menuNav ul { list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:auto; }
#menuNav ul.dynamic { z-index:1; }
#menuNav a { color:Black;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;display:block; }
#menuNav a.static { padding:0px 25px 0px 25px;text-decoration:none; }
#menuNav a.popout { background-image:url("/WebResource.axd?d=YAYach_zykzn7tRotFpEUooSLA5tkKRlrmRHdMCCYTmNa9Zs9n3PZn-rt7_f89W39R3EkyKsYQv4S4ply_deI-3o1z4geNWE-5Ix8Q9QwDY1&t=635809748628077660");background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:right center;padding-right:14px; }
#menuNav a.static.highlighted { background-color:#009933; }
/* ]]> */
</style></head>
<body style="z-index: 1; width:100%; height:100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;padding:0px">
    <form method="post" action="./EditEmployeeList.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=fqV81KWLWhVg-lLAb4IT6-p-eeOqGFN1Vw23T9wDCBE-sWuX9u3xhwkV7mKX_fWFt1SVEu5uaf0gNs953EjMb2qYYRl4UBd4LbawvWTeHE81&amp;t=635809748628077660" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <table  style ="border-collapse: collapse;width:100%" >
            <tr style ="height:50px; background-color: #379f1e">

                <td>
                    <a href="#menuNav_SkipLink" style="position:absolute;left:-10000px;top:auto;width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;">Skip Navigation Links</a><div id="menuNav">
<ul class="level1">
<li><a class="level1" href="RewardFeed.aspx">Home</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="EmployeeForm.aspx">My Profile</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="SendReward.aspx">Send Reward</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="GiftBoard.aspx">Gifts</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="Cart.aspx">View Shopping Cart</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="WishList.aspx">View Saved List</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="Settings.aspx">Settings</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="AdminHome.aspx">Admin</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="LoginPage.aspx">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</div><a id="menuNav_SkipLink"></a>
                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$btnSearchEmployee" value="Search" id="btnSearchEmployee" class="auto-style7" />
                    <input name="ctl00$txtSearchEmployee" type="text" id="txtSearchEmployee" class="auto-style6" />
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="auto-style5">



    <div>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_employeeGridView" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;z-index: 1; left: 110px; top: 0px; position: absolute; height: 154px; width: 670px">
<tr style="color:White;background-color:#507CD1;font-weight:bold;">
<th scope="col">First Name</th><th scope="col">Middle Initial</th><th scope="col">Last Name</th><th scope="col">Position</th><th scope="col">Email</th><th scope="col">Phone Number</th><th scope="col">Start Date</th><th scope="col">Options</th>
</tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
<td>
name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$employeeGridView$ctl02$btnEdit" value="Edit" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_employeeGridView_btnEdit_0" />
                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$employeeGridView$ctl02$btnDelete" value="Delete" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_employeeGridView_btnDelete_0" />
                </td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:White;">
<td>
name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$employeeGridView$ctl03$btnEdit" value="Edit" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_employeeGridView_btnEdit_1" />
                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$employeeGridView$ctl03$btnDelete" value="Delete" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_employeeGridView_btnDelete_1" />
                </td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
<td>
                   name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$employeeGridView$ctl04$btnEdit" value="Edit" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_employeeGridView_btnEdit_2" />
                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$employeeGridView$ctl04$btnDelete" value="Delete" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_employeeGridView_btnDelete_2" />
                </td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:White;">
<td>
                  name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$employeeGridView$ctl05$btnEdit" value="Edit" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_employeeGridView_btnEdit_3" />
                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$employeeGridView$ctl05$btnDelete" value="Delete" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_employeeGridView_btnDelete_3" />
                </td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
<td>
                   name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$employeeGridView$ctl06$btnEdit" value="Edit" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_employeeGridView_btnEdit_4" />
                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$employeeGridView$ctl06$btnDelete" value="Delete" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_employeeGridView_btnDelete_4" />
                </td>
</tr><tr style="color:White;background-color:#507CD1;font-weight:bold;">
<td>

</tr>
</table>
</div>
        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblWorks" class="auto-style8" style="color:Green;"></span>
        <br />
        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblError" class="auto-style10" style="color:Red;"></span>
         <br />       


    </div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="6B608C7D" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" id="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="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" />
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'menuNav', disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'horizontal', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });</script></form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you share how the HTML is being generated?

Comment: What do you mean by how it's being generated? Sorry, a bit new to this.

Comment: Browse the page, right click, view source

Comment: Got it. Check above, deleted a few lines not relevant to the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: The HTML looks broken here <td>
name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$employeeGridView$ctl02$btnEdit" value="Edit" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_employeeGridView_btnEdit_0" />
                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$employeeGridView$ctl02$btnDelete" value="Delete" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_employeeGridView_btnDelete_0" />
                </td>

Comment: This HTML is the output of server-side ASP.NET webforms code. It's impossible to look at the HTML and guess what the problem might be with the server-side code that produced it. If we had that to look at... that would still be really hard. I pasted your HTML into a file and opened it in my browser. The beginning of the input tag is missing from the edit buttons. When I fix that both buttons are inside the "First Name" column. ASP.NET isn't going to product HTML with missing tags, so this must have been altered, making it 10x more impossible for anyone to make sense of it.

Comment: I'd recommend removing ALL your CSS.  It should look normal.  Then add it back in piece by piece and see what breaks the layout.